# Ruby On Rails: Database model Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database-design, model

I want to develop a blog application. In which a user can create a post and comment on the post. A post can have many comments from user and it should belong to user. And, same way comment should belongs to user and blog. So, that I can identify which comment belongs to which post and which user has commented on post.

So, I have made association among models as below

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :comments
   has_many :posts, through: :comments
end

class Post < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :comments
   has_many :users, through: :comments
end

class Comment < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :post
   belongs_to :user
end
```

Now, my question is how do I identify which user has created the post. I want to add a `user_id` in **Post** model, so that I can identify who is the author of Post.

Would it solve my problem?, if I write something like this in **Post** model

```
belongs_to :author, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "user_id"
```

How will migration files look?. I am looking for your suggestion and help. Is there a better way to associate these models?

Your help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are proposing will work, but your syntax seems backward.

I would expect `@user.posts` to return "posts that this user created", not "posts that have comments by this user"

I would expect `@post.user` to return "the user who authored this post", but you have `@post.users` returning "all users who commented on this post"

I would strive for these methods:

- `@user.posts` returns all post this user created ("authored")
- `@user.comments` returns all comments this user created
- `@user.commented_posts` returns all posts this user has commented on
- `@post.user` returns the user who created ("authored") this post
- `@post.comments` returns all comments related to this post
- `@post.commented_users` returns all users who have commented on this post
- `@comment.user` returns the user who created this comment
- `@comment.post` returns the post associated with this comment

By doing this:

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts # "authored" posts
  has_many :comments
  has_many :commented_posts, through: :comments, source: :post
end

class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :comments
  belongs_to :user # author
  has_many :commented_users, through: :comments, source: :user
end

class Comment < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :post
 belongs_to :user # commentor
end
```

Comment: I think you mean to say `Post has_many :comments`... probably just a typo

Comment: Thanks, It works like a charm. to make ```@post.commented_users``` Post class should have ```has_many :commented_users, through: :comments, source: :user```. correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You're right! Added that relationship.